# Calculating the distance between 2 points in 2D Space?

Tags: math, 2d, distance

So the formula is basically: 
    xd = x2-x1
    yd = y2-y1
    Distance = sqrt(xd * xd  + yd * yd)

But surely the formula has to be different depending on whether something is above, below, left, or right of the other object?

Like, if I have a sprite in the middle of the screen, and an enemy somewhere below, would that require changing the "x2-x1" (Let's just say the player sprite is x1, enemy is x2) the other way around if the enemy was above instead?

Comment: Work through a few simple examples, perhaps on squared paper, and you'll easily figure this out for yourself.

Comment: Although it will make no difference for 'normal sized' numbers, I think its worth getting into the habit of using the math library function hypot, ie use hypot(x2-x1,y2-y1) instead.

Answer (score 5):

Distance in the sense you describe above will always be a positive value.  The sum of the square of real numbers will always be positive, and the square root of a positive number will also always be positive.  So, it doesn't matter whether you define `xd = x2-x1` or `xd = x1-x2`.  They only differ by their sign and so both have the same absolute value which means they both square to the same value.

So, there aren't really any special cases here.  The formulation of the distance measure accommodates all of the concerns you raise.

Answer (score 3):

Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow (a.X-b.X, 2) + Math.Pow (a.Y-b.Y, 2));

Try this. It should work!

Answer (score 0):

yes, you are very right. In my case, I have to calculate distance between two points in 2D. I put x1 for swarm,x2 for intruder along X-Axis and y1 for intruder and y2 for swarm along Y-Axis. 
d=sqrt((swarm(de,1) - (intruderX)).^2 + (swarm(de,2)-intruderY).^2); 
[Distance is not calculated accurately, I want when intruder comes inside the circle of any swarm particle, it must be detected][1], some times, intruder comes inside the circle but not be detected. This is my problem. Anyone, who solve my problem, will be very grateful to them.
    for de = 1:Ndrones
    d = sqrt((swarm(de,1) - (intruderX)).^2 + (swarm(de,2)-intruderY).^2);
    if(d<=rad)            %  intruder has been detected
    x = intruderX;
    y = intruderY;
    title('Intruder Detected');
    text(x,y+5,sprintf('Intruder'));
    text(500,900,sprintf('Iterations: %.2f',iter));
    plot(swarm(:,1),swarm(:,2));
    for i=1:Ndrones
    swarm(:, 9) = 100; %restart the minimum calculation
    end
    return;
    end 
    end     % end of de loop
    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBP27.png

Comment: Hi Gul Rukh Khan, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Your answer looks quite thorough, but it is very difficult to read; can you format it to make it more legible? You should be able to separate out the code snippets and use markdown to make the different parts of your answer clearer.